# SQL Database Migration to Salesforce/Another CRM (One Time Import)

Tags: mysql, sql, migration, salesforce, crm

Currently have a ~2GB CRM database that's built on mysql + cold fusion and running on our local MS2012 server. Looking to move it to a more usable/up-to-date solution that would allow flexibility, security, and back-up solutions. Also no longer going to be running on cold fusion.

I received the full backup database in a .bak and have restored successfully in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio so I see the massive list of tables, views, programmability, service broker, storage, security.

Salesforce seems to be a good bet, as we would likely be able to hire someone in the event that I leave so someone could pick it back up and work with it. Also, Salesforce makes sense in what we're trying to do with the CRM.

I'm unsure about how to do this migration. Right now I'm working on a backup copy to practice and put a process in place to ensure we have a smooth transition because the company is still doing their day to day on CF until we have a set in stone stop date to do the transfer. It'll be a one-time transfer so I don't need to establish a constant connection, I just want to pull in all the database tables, values, relationships, etc and then get everyone setup. I realize pulling in users with login information might not be feasible and I would have to create users in salesforce. I do want to have the data that each user has put in retained though.

There might be some additional data you guys need to fully answer the question so please let me know if I have some crucial gaps that would help get the proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

DBAmp is pretty much industry standard at this point. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016bWzEAI. It will allow you to do CRUD from SQL.

Also, when you sign an agreement with Salesforce, they will also hook you up with an integration partner to whom you will pay large sums of money to help you with the transition.

Edit: Sorry, I guess I didn't really answer your full question. Yes, you are missing large, LARGE pieces of information. DBAmp will help you with your data, but don't think you will just be able to import your data structure over.